# ffmpeg Convert audio files to mp3 using ffmpeg same quality

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I convert audio files to mp3 with original file's audio quality?

```
ffmpeg -i audio.ogg -f mp3 newfile.mp3
```

I want to know is that code converts with same quality?

Comment: What do you mean by "with the same quality"? Do you mean "without perceptible loss of quality", or "with the same (average) bitrate"?

Comment: bitrate, but if u know something about "without perceptible loss of quality" please tell

Comment: MP3 is a lossy codec. If you want to minimize quality loss, use a high bit rate. For example `ffmpeg -i audio.ogg -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 0 newfile.mp3` will use the highest quality VBR (variable bit rate) preset from the Lame MP3 encoder, which will _usually_ give you a file with an average bit rate between 220 and 260 kb/s. If your input file has a relatively low bit rate (e.g. 128 kb/s or less), and you use the same bit rate when transcoding to MP3, the resulting sound quality is going to be worse than the original.

Comment: Please do not crosspost the [same question](http://superuser.com/questions/1053110/ffmpeg-convert-audio-files-to-mp3-using-ffmpeg-same-quality) on multiple Stack Exchange sites. Your question is offtopic here since it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 6):

it is impossible. FFmpeg cannot search for you input file's bit rate and then cannot copy funded bit rate to output.  We need to find the input file's bit rate then we need to convert to mp3. This code converts audio files to mp3 with 320 kbps bit rate.

```
ffmpeg -i 31352.m4a -ab 320k -f mp3 newfile.mp3
```

Comment: Copying the bitrate would not do what you want and you're comparing two different encoder implementations for two different lossy formats.